# How autoscaling works in Google compute engine vm instance group

Tags: google-compute-engine, gce-instance-group

I have created instance group for windows in google compute engine based on CPU Utilization(60%) and I executed simple while loop program to make use CPU more than 60% on first instance in group.
         As CPU load increases in first instance, instance group automatically started few more instances in group to handle the load. But I don't see my program running in that other instances but CPU utilization is showing increased in those extra instances also.
Can anyone help how exactly it share CPU load between instances in group?

Thanks In Advance...